# Updating billion rows table

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, bulkupdate

We are having a table with billion rows. We just want to UPDATE two columns to NULL for all rows. We were trying to do this in batches. But, we are concerned about the performance issues. We are having clustered columnstore index on this table. Does creating composite non-clustered index on these three columns would help ?  or can we re-load the table to new table & swap the tables ?

Any inputs will be very helpful.

```
DECLARE @notNULLRecordsCount INT; 

SET @notNULLRecordsCount = 1;

WHILE @notNULLRecordsCount > 0 
    BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    UPDATE  TOP (100000)
    dbo.BillionRowsTable
    SET     Column1 = NULL,
            Column2 = NULL,
            Column3 = NULL     
    WHERE   Column1 IS NOT NULL OR Column2 IS NOT NULL OR Column3 IS NOT NULL;


SET @notNULLRecordsCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

Comment: There is a fast way to do that by adding new columns such as Column1_New with the desired data type, drop the old column and rename the Column1_New to the original name, however, this is of course if you don't need to apply any logic and you don't have any schema bounded views on this table, and that the order of the columns is not important to you or your application

Comment: You're missing a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.  How many other indexes, constraints etc are there on the table

Comment: also try with(rowlock) , but i do not believe this will help, but will help others have access to the table  , without doing it in batches

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik A billion rows would flood the transaction log.

Comment: @hkravitz thanks for the suggestion. the problem with this is, we are having DACPAC based deployment, when the schema changes, everytime, the deployment will try to create new table with new schema and reload billion rows and swap tables. our future DACPAC deployments will fail.

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze Added COMMIT. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My experience is that indexes actually slow this down as the indexes must be maintained.

Leaving a transaction open is not good.  Wrapping all these in a transaction is not good.  If you are going to wrap them all in a transaction then no purpose to breaking them up.

If you could key on just one column (no `or`) it would be faster.

You can shorten this

```
select 1;
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE  TOP (100000)
    dbo.BillionRowsTable
    SET     Column1 = NULL,
            Column2 = NULL,
            Column3 = NULL     
    WHERE   Column1 IS NOT NULL 
         OR Column2 IS NOT NULL 
         OR Column3 IS NOT NULL
END
```

To get rid of the `or`

```
select 1;
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE  TOP (100000)
    dbo.BillionRowsTable
    SET     Column1 = NULL,
            Column2 = NULL,
            Column3 = NULL     
    WHERE   Column1 IS NOT NULL
END

select 1;
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE  TOP (100000)
    dbo.BillionRowsTable
    SET     Column2 = NULL,
            Column3 = NULL     
    WHERE   Column2 IS NOT NULL
END

select 1;
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE  TOP (100000)
    dbo.BillionRowsTable
    SET     Column3 = NULL     
    WHERE   Column3 IS NOT NULL
END
```

Comment: Curious. What purpose does the 'select 1;' serve?

Comment: @EricBrandt To have a @@ROWCOUNT

Comment: Ok, I see what you did there. Thx for spelling it out for me. Also, using the UPDATE (or DELETE for that matter) TOP(x) strategy, in order to make sure other users have a chance to access the table, I've added something like a WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.50' to the mix between iterations.

Comment: @EricBrandt I see not reason to slow it down

Comment: @paparazzo When there are huge number of updates, there is little delay in the hardening of the log and we find WRITELOG wait type happening. Having this WAITFOR DELAY will help in hardening the log.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion by @Paparazzo, we have decided to do this as a two staged UPDATE, using single column. We do once using Column1 as NULL and another one using Column1 as NOT NULL, so that we cover all the rows.

```
select 1;
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
BEGIN 
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE  TOP (100000)
    dbo.BillionRowsTable
    SET     Column2 = NULL,
            Column3 = NULL     
    WHERE   Column1 IS NULL;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END

select 1;
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
BEGIN 
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE  TOP (100000)
    dbo.BillionRowsTable
    SET     Column1= NULL,
            Column2 = NULL,
            Column3 = NULL     
    WHERE   Column1 IS NOT NULL;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```